# How to top align paragraph of texts in multiple different Swing text components?

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextarea, jtextpane

I'm trying to make a text editor in Java for translators that put the original text side by side with the translation, something to the effect of [EU journal multilingual display](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN-FR-DE/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32015R0501&from=EN), where the same paragraph in different languages visually begins on a level horizontal line.

I'd like the texts to be contained within different text elements(of type JTextArea, JTextPane or JEditorPane). The text elements will have line wrapping enabled. Then the application should somehow adjust the spacing after each paragraph so that it looks like the above web page.

There might be a scroll bar to move all panes to the same position, or I may just sync the scroll position of all the panels.

How can I achieve the above objectives?

Here is what I currently have:

[image: Tri panel Swing layout]

Comment: I would use 3 JTextPanes enclosed in a single JScrollPane.  I'd have a [StyledDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) for each of the 3 JTextPanes, and control the paragraph spacing myself in the StyledDocuments.

Comment: Which EditorKit you use for the JTextPanes? Just simple StyledEditorKit?

Comment: To align the paragraphs, I think that you would need [modelToView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) method. Use it with the [getParagraphElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) method to get where each paragraph is currently drawn and to adapt it if necessary

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Yup the main point is about how to control the paragraph spacing :) I'm not sure about StyledDocument and stuff at all... Will read the documentation.

Comment: @StanislavL TBH I just used JTextArea for now

Comment: @Sharcoux Thanks. I really have to read up on StyledDocument now haha. But I'm feeling lazy O.o

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far? It might be easier to discuss possible approaches when there is some code to look at and modify.